# How to make flutter custom drop down button?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdownbutton

I want to Customise [`DropDownButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html), so that it  does not render the content of [`DropdownItem`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenuItem-class.html). Instead it should render my Custom layout/widget before and after selecting an item from DropDown.
In simple Words, I want to customise my [`DropDownButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).

Thanks,

Comment: Checking how Dropdown is implemented, I think you will need to edit in the source implementation in order to do that as it checks if value=null or else value takes the item value and not a subset of it.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you are trying to achive?

Comment: @HemanthRaj making dropdown value customization rather than reflecting the choice (choosing A will make dropdownButton value = A, what about if I choose A, the dropdownButton value = B instead)

Answer (score 6):

How to render `DropdownButton` items differently when it is dropped down?

I found a solution through `DropdownMenuItem`. Its `build()` is executed separately for closed and dropped down state. You can use the context to find out if it is closed or dropped down state. e.g you can check for an ancestor stateful widget.

I use something like this dummy code fragment:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selectedItem.id,
    items: items.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: item.id,
            child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final bool isDropDown = context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<PageState>()) == null;

                if (isDropDown) {
                    return Text(item.name);
                } else {
                    return Text(item.name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
                }
            },)
        );
    }).toList(),
);
```

Where *items* is a list of *id-name* instances, and *PageState* is the state of my own stateful widget.

Comment: so this works. the issue I'm having is getting the dropdown width to expand where the dropdown items ares larger than the button...