# How to give dropdownitems a larger width than the container( Dropdown Button ) in flutter

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter app. I have a dropdownbutton on the appbar. There is a search bar next to it, so I don't want it to take too much space when it isn't open. I want it to take as much space as possible when it is opened.

I expect it to act as shown in the links below. Sorry, stack overflow won't allow me to include the images here.
[not open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwwBX.jpg)       [open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEkL1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the problem exactly ? Please see [ask] and give a [mcve] from your tries

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming. I am a newbie here. I wanted to replicate what I have done on native android ( The app shown in the links to the images) using flutter. I couldn't find a way to give the drop down items full width only when they are listed( not in condensed mode).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make flutter custom drop down button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024142/how-to-make-flutter-custom-drop-down-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question shows how to make the popup different, you can use the same strategy: [How to make flutter custom drop down button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024142/how-to-make-flutter-custom-drop-down-button?rq=1)

Comment: This is a really nice approach! It can make the popup different, but for some reason it is not enabling me to give the popup a greater width than the collapsed one.

Comment: Hmm, I would inspect up the tree and see what's forcing the width and see if I can modify it for the two case...